How to access data using private link and how frontend developer will render data
I'm working on a application where i will store images, videos on S3 bucket. I have created a private bucket and want to access data using private link. I'm sure that i will have to use VPC for this but my real question is how we will access data through VPC and how frontend developer will show data on UI. I don't want to use presigned URL (problem if there are millions of images or video then how this process will happen) or a stream (problem is if there are 20 chunk of a video file then how will i manage it) to render images. so is there different solution in term of complexity. i am using java as a backend language.
I have tried both a presigned URL and a stream concept but they are not suitable solutions for my problem.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

The correct answer is to use an Amazon S3 pre-signed URL. You can generate it in a couple of lines of code at the time that the link is required. It does not need a call to AWS and does not need to be stored anywhere. There is no problem if there are "millions of images or video" because it is generated as-needed. Why do you say that you do not want to use it?

An Amazon S3 pre-signed URL is exactly what you should be using.
The process is:

The user authenticates to your application
When your back-end app wishes to provide a link to a private object, it verifies that the user is entitled to access the object
If they are authorized, your app creates an Amazon S3 pre-signed URL, which provides time-limited access to the private object. This is generated in a couple of lines of code and does not require an API call to Amazon S3. The app provides this pre-signed URL in the web page (eg in <img> tag).
When the user clicks or uses the link, Amazon S3 verifies that the pre-signed URL is valid and is still within the expiry time. If so, it provides access to the private object.

It does not matter that you have "millions of images or video" -- the pre-signed URL is generated when the web page is being generated.

Thanks for answering john but i want to ask one more case suppose i have video of 10 MB so i will store it in chunk so will i create link for every chunk .suppose if a video have 20 chunk then  will i create  20 link.  actually in my problem if a book's isbn have 5 images and 2 video so will i create link for each and will share to frontend developer together.

Yes. Whenever you would provide a link to the user (either directly or embedded in an HTML page), first convert it to a pre-signed URL and then provide it to the user. That way, it remains private but authorized users can access it for a defined time period. You should only create the pre-signed URL at the time that it is required. If your back-end normally provides a URL to the front-end, then the front-end won't need any changes since the back-end would generate the pre-signed URL.

Thanks for your valuable response john. Now after discussing to my team i will use this mechanism to generate signed URL using java SDK.
